# How would you graph fiscal year data together with calendar year data?

Tags: data-visualization, excel

I have two datasets resembling the toy example below:

```
* FY        . Cats 
* 2016-2017 . 1
* 2017-2018 . 2 
* 2018-2019 . 3


 Year .   Dogs
* 2016 .   3
* 2017 .   2
* 2018 .   1
```

I would like to present both of these on a graph, but because the first table's data is in fiscal year, and the other is in calendar year, I am unsure what the best way to visualize this trend would be.

How would you graph these two datasets together, preferably in Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Excel graphing, but a general approach is to plot horizontal lines from the beginning to end of each year. It can be done with or without fill, depending on aesthetics and how many values you have.

[image]

Most of the work if often getting the data in the right form. Here's the data arrangement I used to make a line/area plot in JMP.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply Xan, that makes a lot of sense!